# Binary/Int File reading & Array Storage

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, binary

Trying to help a friend, I'm not asking for code.

I have a text file that has integers that are sorted in binary form. 100010101001010101010.
How would I go about reading 8 ints at a time to make a byte, then store that as a int, stuff that into an array of ints. I cannot use strings, or anything with dynamic allocation. The numbers are on one line. I have to seperate them myself through the program.

I thought about using a for loop with a pointer reading each int at and append them to an int, throwing that int into the array. Something like (excuse me for paraphrasing coding, I haven't touched it in a while.)

```
while(eof) //end of file
{
    for(int i = 0, i > 9, i ++)
    {
    pointer read file seekg()
    int += seekg()  // minus the part where its mathematically adding im thinking of     str+= str 
    //i know its the wrong code
    }

x++
array [x] = int from for loop
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: A little light on the specifics of the file format, can you provide a better example of the input data please. value separations, are all the int values provided in full 32 bits, or are they arbitrary in length separated by whitespace,etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop and in each and every iteration, you will be going over each and every digit. Multiply the first digit by `2^7` and second digit by `2^6` and like that go on till your `8th` digit (multiple by `2^0`). Also while going through this add this number and store in a vector or array. Also, have a variable which tracks the current position on the digits. Because, after every `8` digits, you have to perform the same above said process to convert the `8 bit binary` to a `byte`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've already broken it down into steps:

- read 8 digits at a time to make a byte
- then store that as a int
- stuff that into an array of ints

That's great! Let's look at each.

First, you need to read the file one character at a time. The C standard library provides a function for this: `fgetc`. Pass in a `FILE *`, it'll give you back the ASCII value of the number it read, or `EOF` (-1) when you've hit the end of the file.

So, we know we can use `fgetc`, and without any line breaks, we know it'll return `'1'`, `'0'`, or `EOF`. Put another way:

```
10001101 => successive fgetc() calls will return
  '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1,' '0', '1', 'EOF'
```

This sounds like a loop:

```
for (int bits = 0; bits < 8; bits++) {
  int digit = fgetc(file);
  if (digit == '0') {
    // something
  } else if (digit == '1') {
    // something else
  } else if (digit == EOF) {
    // done with the file
  }
}
```

All right. Now, how do we assemble 0s and 1s into a binary number? The answer is bit shifting. We set up a variable to hold the output number, then repeatedly set the lowest bit and shift the other bits up. So:

```
10001101
'1' =>        1
'0' =>       10
'0' =>      100
'0' =>     1000
'1' =>    10001
'1' =>   100011
'0' =>  1000110
'1' => 10001101
```

So:

```
int number = 0;
for (int bits = 0; bits < 8; bits++) {
  // shift number up one place
  number = number << 1;

  int digit = fgetc(file);
  if (digit == '0') {
    // do nothing; the lowest bit is 0 already
  } else if (digit == '1') {
    // set number's lowest bit
    number |= 0x01;
  } else if (digit == EOF) {
    // done with the file
  }
}
```

Now all you need to do is wrap that in another loop that puts `number` in an array. That's just a matter of remembering how many numbers you've already stored (a counter), and then escaping from the loop when you hit the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C++ example of how to write integers in binary form out to a file, and how to read the binary data back as integers in the same program.  Comments are in the program, hopefully this helps.

This assumes your machine acknowledges data type `char` as 1 byte, and `int` as 4 bytes.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { 

    ofstream outFile; // File which we will write binary data to.
    ifstream inFile;  // File which we will read binary data from.

    outFile.open( "intBin.txt", ios::binary ); // Flag file as binary.

    for( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i ) {
            // This writes 4 bytes out to file.
        outFile.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), sizeof(int) );
    }
    outFile.close(); // Must close, since race conditions will occur accessing same file in same process of our program.

    inFile.open("intBin.txt", ios::binary); // Flag file as binary.
    int binVals;
    for( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i ) {
            // This reads 4 bytes back into the file.
        inFile.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&binVals), sizeof(int) );
        cout << binVals << endl;
    }
    inFile.close();

}
```

Comment: The integers in the file are text. i.e. read the first byte and its 0x31 (ascii byte for '1'). binary reads/writes are not what he's dealing with.